# Enable/Disable Parallel Execution of Features / Scenarios in Karate

Tags: karate

I am looking for a way to enable/disable parallel execution of Karate feature files / scenarios.

I understand it is not a good practice to have interdependent scenarios, but I need to make sure a counter in database is always incremented by a certain amount every time each scenario is executed. So parallel execution of scenarios kind of messes up the entire test suite as the assertion is no longer accurate.

So I need a method to turn off parallel execution (maybe based on a flag in `karate-config.js`?), so that there is an option to run the tests in parallel when this counter tests is not required. I am currently applying `@parallel=false` in each and every feature files, and have no way to easily turn parallel execution back on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the references you seem to have read already, the only option is to set threads to 1, take it or leave it. You are welcome to contribute code if you don't like it.